# Why does APARCH become EGARCH when $\delta$ goes to zero?

Tags: time-series, garch

Here is the APARCH(1,1):

$$\sigma^\delta_t = c + \alpha(|a_{t-1}|+\gamma a_{t-1} )^\delta + \beta \sigma^\delta_{t-1}\,.$$

My question is, why it becomes an EGARCH model when $\delta$ goes to 0?

EGARCH(1,1):

$$\ln(\sigma^2_t)=c+ \alpha \frac{|a_{t-1}|+\gamma a_{t-1}}{\sigma_{t-1}} +\beta \ln(\sigma^2_{t-1}) \, .$$

I tried to use Taylor expansion of $\sigma^\delta_t$, but still cannot get the exact proof.

Comment: See [this link][1] at Appendix A, page 20 (102) 


  [1]: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.471.7587&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: Thanks. I read the paper. The paper says APARCH model become log-ARCH model when $\delta$ goes to zero. But log-ARCH model is slightly different from the EGARCH model.